# TFS : How to identify it's system or custom field for the work item type template?

Tags: c#, tfs

In TFS, How to identify field of work item is custom (user created) or system (by default it will come with template)? I need to know the way using C# and TFS explorer also.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in the existing system to determine which field comes with the shipped templates and which one you have added later yourself out of the gate. The only way to do that is by downloading the templates from your server, crack open the zip file and then scan the work item type xml's.

In the new world of process customization which is already available in VS Team Services (the cloud version) and will ship eventually to on-prem, you will be able to. And then we will also have proper REST API support. But for now your options are very limited.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks Ewald for the information. When will be REST API support available for this?

Comment: I have no ETA for the APIs, but as they come available it will be documented in this location: https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/tfs/processes